# Select Data from table with a Date interval MySql PHP

Tags: mysql, date

This is my table called `Movies` which has the following data:

```
movie_id | movie_title |  movie_Date  | views  |
---------+-------------+--------------+--------+
1        | Movie 1     |2016-03-10    | 15     |
2        | Movie 2     |2016-02-14    | 12     |
3        | Movie 3     |2016-01-27    | 50     |
4        | Movie 4     |2016-01-21    | 13     |
5        | Movie 5     |2015-12-30    | 10     |
6        | Movie 6     |2015-12-27    | 83     |
```

And my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE (a date interval based on movie_date and the current system date) ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5
```

I want to modify my query to pick only the movies with a specified date interval.

Comment: It is not really clear for me what `a date interval based on movie_date and the current system date` means. can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try :

```
SELECT * FROM `Movies` WHERE `movie_Date` BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2;
```

This is the best approach. Enjoy.

Comment: Why is it the best approach?

Comment: Please try it out and see. There might be other ways to fetch `BETWEEN` two dates but this is the best. If it wasn't a `BETWEEN` then a `LIKE` would be the best approach.

Comment: What  mean is why your way is better than the other `between` ways you can see in the other answers?

Comment: Its just the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `between` for that:

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE movie_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query into something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE (movie_Date >= startDate and movie_Date <= endDate) ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` gives your specified date interval.

and that should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE(movie_date BETWEEN movie_date AND NOW()) ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Movies` WHERE `movie_Date` BETWEEN $date1 AND NOW() ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5
```

Hope this helps